# how to make background application should be clickable from transparent activity theme in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I created an activity having translucent theme with a single button.It's Working fine with 100% transparent, when button is clicked it display a toast message.

But outside of window is not clickable,i want outside of window should be clickable(i.e behind my transparent activity). How can i achieve it?

**TransparentActivity.java:**

```
public class TransparentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
  setContentView(R.layout.button_test);
  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btun1);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  System.out.println("Motion event: " + event.getAction());
  if (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE == event.getAction()) {
   Log.v(LOG_TAG, "OUTSIDE CLICKED");
  }
  return true;
 }
}
```

Layout **button_test.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_id"
        android:text="CLICK"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Custom **Theme:**

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
            android:name=".TransparentActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
</activity>
```